# Listar o valor de um Subscribe no Angular 2+

Tags: typescript, angular

Tenho um componente que faz ligação com um outro componente irmão. A partir disso, fiz um serviço para que seja possível fazer essa comunicação. Até ai tudo bem. O problema é que eu não consigo recuperar os valores do *subscribe* que está dentro de um componente para poder listar.

table.component.ts:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from './../service/shared.service';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'table-component',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.scss']
})

export class TableComponent implements OnInit {

  private value: any;
  private data: any;
  private filteredValues = [];
  private message: string = 'Utilize os filtros acima para exibir especialidades, ou';

  constructor(private service: SharedService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    /* Get JSON results */
    this.service.getApi().subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data;      
    })

    /* Filter click button */
    this.service.currentValue.subscribe(value => {
      this.filteredValues = [];
      this.value = value;
      if(this.data !== undefined){
        console.log('value',this.value)
        console.log('data', this.data)
        for(let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++){
          if(this.data[i].codeId == this.value[0].code && this.data[i].rowId == this.value[0].row){
            this.filteredValues.push(this.data[i]);
          }
        }
        console.log(this.filteredValues);
      }
    })
  }

}
```

shared.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

const URL = '../../assets/api.json';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
currentValue = this.messageSource.asObservable();

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

changeMessage(message: any) {
 this.messageSource.next(message)
}

getApi(){
  return this.http.get(URL);
}
```

}

Queria consumir esse *array* `filteredValues`, porém, ele não me mostra nada. Sei que está relacionado ao subscribe, mas não tenho a menor ideia de como resolver.